# How to order/design a shared library with CMake that use higher includes

Tags: c++, include, cmake, include-path

At the moment I have a shared library with around ~30 classes. My idea is to group them into subdirectories, means a subdirectory contains classes that are more or less equals/have the same content (ui, utils, backend etc).

But I ran into a typical problem: I have some export defines/constants that are shared across the project and my first question was: How to include this header from a header in a subdirectory ?

I often see the `#include ../Header.h` solution but my personal opinion is, that this is quite ugly.

So what I did:

```
Application/
      main.cpp
MyLibrary/
      Header.h
      foo/
            Foo.h (#include <Header.h>
      bar/
            Bar.h (#include <Header.h> #include <foo/Foo.h>)
```

And in my library CMakeList I add and `include_directory` with the root directory of the MyLibrary directory.

My application executable CMakeLists.txt looks something like this (pseudo CMake)

```
project(application)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../)

add_executable(application main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(application mylibrary)
```

And in the `main.cpp` I include like this:

```
#include <MyLibrary/Header.h>
#include <MyLibrary/bar/Bar.h>
```

**The problem now** is, that the compiler doesn't know where to look for the included <> **INSIDE** the library, for example the Header.h includation inside foo.bar points to `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Header.h` - but `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` is the path of the application and NOT of the library

So I have to add the directory of the library that the compiler can found the other headers of the library (Header in the library that includes another Header in the library via <> and not "")

So I end up with something like this:

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../ ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../MyLibrary)
```

And now Bar.h can find foo/Foo.h, otherwise something goes wrong. And this is even more ugly

**So my question:** Is there a good/tricky way to solve this problem in CMake ? Or can someone give me tipps about a better project structure ? The solution has to run under MSVC, GCC and clang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think about how your library will look after install you may get some hints about structure. So for example:

```
<install-prefix>/Foo/foo.hpp -> has `#include <Boo/boo.hpp>`
<install-prefix>/Boo/boo.hpp -> has `#include <Bar/bar.hpp>`
<install-prefix>/Bar/bar.hpp -> has `#include <Bar/details/utils.hpp>`
<install-prefix>/Bar/details/utils.hpp
```

this is possible layout before install done:

```
<source-dir>/Sources/Foo/foo.hpp
<source-dir>/Sources/Boo/boo.hpp
<source-dir>/3rdParty/Bar/bar.hpp
<source-dir>/3rdParty/Bar/details/utils.hpp
```

hence `CMakeLists.txt` must contains (or better [target_include_directories](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html)):

```
include_directories(<source-dir>/Sources)
include_directories(<source-dir>/3rdParty)
```

so for your case, IMHO it must be something like that:

```
Application/
    main.cpp
MyLibrary/
    Header.h
    foo/
        Foo.h (#include <MyLibrary/Header.h>
    bar/
        Bar.h (#include <MyLibrary/Header.h> #include <MyLibrary/foo/Foo.h>)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know about this awesome target_include_directories command. Now I can also define interfaces and private headers - perfect!

Answer (score 0):

What I've done to solve this problem is have a top level CMakeLists.txt that sets variables that will point to the top of the project directory. In your case this will be the directory containing **Application** and **MyLibrary**.

```
ProjectRoot
CMakeLists.txt // top
   Application/
      CMakeLists.txt
      main.cpp
   MyLibrary/
      CMakeLists.txt
      Header.h
      foo/
            Foo.h (#include <Header.h>
      bar/
            Bar.h (#include <Header.h> #include <foo/Foo.h>)

# Top level cmakelists
project (myproject)
set (my_app_src_top "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" )
set (my_app_build_top "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}" )
add_subdirectory( MyLibrary )
add_subdirectory( Application )
```

Then in your subdirectory CmakeLists, you can add include paths like this:

```
include_directories( ${my_app_src_top}/MyLibrary )
```

I also just define a project at the top level CMakeLists.txt. In this case you may be able to reference  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}, but if you define projects in sub directories, then I think this will get reset based on the last sub directory you built.

I think with this structure you should be able to

```
#include <foo/Foo.h>
#include <bar/Bar.h>
```

Plus you may want to add ./ to the include_directories for each sub dir.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I prefer the accepted solution because every target that links against a library target automatically includes the includes given by this target. That saves a few CMake lines and makes the whole thing directory independant. But your answer is also a valid solution :)